# FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() vs RedirectToAction("Login", "Account")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am using Forms Authentication in my website. I have seen in some example code that one can call .SignOut() and then use

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

to send a user to the login page.

What advantage, if any, does this have over calling

```
RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```

in an MVC website? From MSDN it seems that the former will not call HttpResponse.End() which means that code that follows will execute... I'm not sure when I would need to use this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()` does have some advantage where it will attempt to append `?ReturnUrl={url}` to the login page URL which can be used later to return the user to the page they were requesting when the login redirect happened. Using this method uses `Response.Redirect()` which goes against the MVC mentality. You'll lose out on events like `OnActionExecuting` from firing in your controller/filters. <sup>[source code of `RedirectToLoginPage`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs,60b1242530802695)</sup>

`RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");` doesn't have the `ReturnUrl` feature out of the box, but it does keep everything in the MVC ecosystem so the events fire. In the case if logging someone out and redirecting back to the login page, I'd probably keep it all in MVC and use `RedirectToAction`. Or potentially use `Redirect(FormsAuthentication.Url);` if you always want to use the login page URL from the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `SignOut()`, but then return a `HttpUnauthorizedResult` so that the controller will just use it's regular login redirect.

If you are signing out in your `OnActionExecuting` controller event, do it this way...

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (//I need to log out...) {
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        filterContext.Result=new System.Web.Mvc.HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        return;
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```