# How can i sign-out and redirect to the login page from a public static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i sign-out and redirect to the login page from a public static class?
I have tried the following but it does not stop page execution..

```
public static DatabaseNameEntities CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName(bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
        {
            string database_name = "";
            try
            {
                database_name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["DB_NAME"].ToString();
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException) 
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }

            //Initialize the SqlConnectionStringBuilder


            //Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder

            //Create entity connection
            EntityConnection connection = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);

            return new DatabaseNameEntities(connection);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not stop page execution"? Try adding a `return null;` after `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();`.

Comment: @OrElse Can you paste the code which is calling this code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried the following but it does not stop page execution..

That's because it's simply not the MVC way.  It's also breaks the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), that is, why would a method named `CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName()` know *anything* about MVC or logging out a user.  The code you posted generally breaks this principle multiple times (application state, signing out a user).

Additionally, catching an exception you can prevent is also [poor practice (or as the Lead Developer for the C# Compiler team called it, Boneheaded Exceptions)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Consider the following code.

```
public static ControllerBaseExtensions
{
  private const string DBNAME = "DB_NAME";

  public static bool TryGetDatabaseName(this ControllerBase instance,
    out string DbName)
  {
    DbName = null;

    var app = GetApp(instance);

    var result = app.Any(k => k == DBNAME);
    if (result)
    {
      DbName = instance.Application[DBNAME] as string;
      result = DbName != null;
    }
    return result;
  }
  public static void SetDatabaseName(this ControllerBase instance,
    string DbName)
  {
    var app = GetApp(instance);

    app[DBNAME] = DbName;
  }
  private static HttpApplication GetApp(ControllerBase instance)
  {
    return instance.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Application;
  }
}

public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
  string DbName;
  if (!this.TryGetDatabaseName(out DbName))
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509980
    RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
  }

  CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName(Dbname);
}


public static DatabaseNameEntities CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName(
  string dbName,
  bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
{

  //Initialize the SqlConnectionStringBuilder

  //Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder

  //Create entity connection
  EntityConnection connection = new
    EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);


  return new DatabaseNameEntities(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does simply ie, no try or catch work as expected

```
    public static DatabaseNameEntities CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName(bool contextOwnsConnection = true)
    {
      FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```